# WPF-проект, создание команды в библиотеке, одинаковое название пространства имён (System.Windows.Input) в разных сборках

Tags: wpf

Visual Studio Версия 17.3.1,
WPF проект, пытаюсь реализовать обычный пример с паттерном MVVM,
но Model и ViewModel сделать в разных библиотеках.

**!В отдельную библиотеку ViewModelLibrary!** кидаем ViewModel и пишем по примеру :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

это не работает!
Visual Studio не даёт собрать библиотеку(

ICommand использует
***using System.Windows.Input***; из сборки **System.ObjectModel.dll**

а на **CommandManager**.RequerySuggested получаем ошибку:

> Ошибка    CS0103  Имя "CommandManager" не существует в текущем контексте.

VS2022 предлагает использовать
***using System.Windows.Input*** НО!!! из сборки **PresentationCore.dll**

т.е. пространства имён совпадают.
Собрать библиотеку нельзя:(
Помогите! Как быть?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы сделали "Библиотеку классов", но не ["Библиотеку классов WPF"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPlZX.png), из-за этого и все ваши проблемы. Открываем `.csprog` (2 раза по названию проекта), дописываем там `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`, находим `TargetFramework` и в конце дописываем `-windows` (должно получиться примерно так: `net6.0-windows`). Сохраняем, пробуем. Таким способом вы свою библиотеку сделали под WPF, студия сама внедрит в нее все необходимые библиотеки (включая `PresentationCore.dll`).

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!!
Добавление "-windows" не помогло, ошибка остаётся, 
но создал новый проект "Библиотека классов WPF" и всё прекрасно работает!!

Огромное спасибо!)

Comment: `Добавление "-windows" не помогло` - так я не только про это сказал, но еще и про `UseWPF`. Тут, конечно, зависит от проекта, на котором пишете. в .NET Framework - там такое не прокатит, надо библиотеки самому подключать, но зачем его использовать в 2022 году...?

Comment: Простите, 
на радостях побежал проверять... UseWPF и не заметил)
Проект Core.

Как Вы считаете ещё актуально писать Windows приложения на WPF? На hh.ru пока много вакансий с WPF...

Или всё же стоит переходить/изучать WinUI 3, MAUI?

Comment: WPF еще очень долго будет жить. По сути, ему еще нет достойной замены. MAUI - очень сырой, имеет ряд ограничений (например, только Win10+), ну и так далее. Исходя из всего этого, если компания разрабатывает софт чисто под Windows, у них есть готовое WPF решение, то они будут и дальше его разрабатывать. Ну а если уклон в кроссплатформенную разработку, то тут уже да, MAUI будет более предпочтителен. Не смотрите на это как на "заработок", смотрите как на "инструмент", лучше уметь и то и то, кто знает как жизнь повернется...

Comment: Спасибо!
Буду дальше грызть гранит науки:)